# How to run a specific condition in script after a specific time in php

Tags: php, time, sleep

I have two ad's and want to run them in difference of 8 hours, means `ad1` start immediately when script start and `ad2` start after 8 hour specified as `28800`Seconds. I am seeking functions `sleep()` and `time_sleep_until()`, but bit confused how to use them between to ad's.

My ad's are defined in array. Also, i tried once `sleep` function in my localhost to execute one ad immediately and another one after `sleep(28800)`, and script continues executing and displays the output of both ad's. It might be a small problem and i didn't apply logic properly.

Comment: Can you provide more information on exactly how these ads are being served? Is the PHP script served through a web server, or is it run on the command line? What do you mean by "immediately when the script starts" in this case? The `sleep(n)` function will keep the current process running for n seconds, which doesn't sound like what you want.

Comment: Not 100% sure of what you mean, but [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) will only delay the execution of the script (stopping in the middle of it) and then displaying the output altogether. If you want to render different ads based on the time of the day, you'll most likely have to maneuver the [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function, and to display them based on a relative time, you'll have to store the `time` at which the ad was switched by the last time in either a db field or txt file and then check against it whenever you load the page.

Comment: @futureal: Yes, php script serve through a web server and publish these ad's in market. Ad's are defined in array: <code> array('name'=>"adname", 'desc'=>"aboutad", 'link'="marketlink");</code> and we encode them into json and send to server. And immediately means when script starts php spawn first ad and after 8 hour it spawn another one. In actual i thought sleep will stop the script for some time and process again  and spawn another ad.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I am using array to define outline of mu ad's in php script. I tried this one : <code><?php
             date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo $date = date("m/d/Y H:i:s a", time()) . '<br />';
$file = array( 'attribute1_value' => "xyz",'attribute2_value' => "Download Best game!!",'attribute3_value' => "http://mydoamin.com/ad.png",'attribute4_value' => "market");

var_dump($file);

//sleep

sleep(100);



?></code>

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: I apologize for bad code formatting

Comment: No problem man, just edit your question to include the code. =] Whenever you edit your question, it's automatically bumped to the top of the newest questions, and if it has some code in it you'll most likely get a quick answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Did you get any idea about this logic=> switching ad's

Comment: @shihon Yeah I do, however I'm falling asleep and still got a lot of unfinished work for tomorrow (which I'm multi-tasking atm), so coming up with a solution from scratch right now isn't quite easy. I'm sure that if you edit your question to include the code, someone will answer it quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like there is some confusion over what PHP is actually responsible for doing here. When somebody makes a request to the web server, a PHP script is being invoked, but then after serving the request, it is done and exits. When the next request comes in, it has no knowledge of the first request.

If you use the `sleep(n)` function to sleep for n seconds, that will pause the response of the web server, which is a very bad idea and not what you are trying to achieve.

Generally speaking, if you want to switch some content based on time, it is better to work off of the server time (which is always known) rather than something like "how long the server has been running" which has no meaning in the real world.

In a simple example, let's say you want to serve 3 different ads based on 8-hour blocks. You might write some code that finds the hour of day, and then selects an ad appropriately. For example:

```
$selection = (date('G',time()) / 8);
switch ($selection) {
  case 0:
    echo 'ad option 1!';
    break;
  case 1:
    echo 'ad option 2!';
    break;
  case 2:
    echo 'ad option 3!';
    break;
}
```

The `date('G',time())` function returns the hour portion of the current system time which will be 0-23. Dividing that by 8 will give you either a 0, 1, or 2, and from there you can select what to display.

Not sure this will satisfy exactly what you are trying to do. If it does not, you may need to involve some kind of database, and have some kind of a job that updates the ad to serve at some interval (I'd avoid this if possible).

Comment: +1 very well explained, I didn't submit an answer as right now I can't think of a better explanation than "PHP runs server-side and spits out generated HTML after it finishes processing hurrdurr", you explained in detail how `sleep()` works and in a simple way, nicely done. And the solution itself is simple and practical.

Comment: @futureal: but if i have to select those ad's randomly for 8 hours, like ad1 is running for 8 hours, ad2 after ad1...how get that this one. Is it possible in script without using database?

Comment: To achieve that, you need to have some kind of persistent information, which would require a database or some other type of server-side storage. You could maybe rig a cron task to update a file every so often and then just serve the contents of that file, but that seems really unnecessary. If you just need to serve a random ad but not always in the same order, you can use other arithmetic tricks like the modulus operator. For example, day of the month % 3 will always give you a value between 0 and 2 that changes based on the day, and so on. But you probably need a database.

Comment: @futureal: i can't using database, only get this done by script, will try your answer with some logic and get back to you if there is problem

Answer (score 0):

You should not run scripts for so long. Use cron instead. You can call the same script at 8 hours difference and based on a db switch call ad_1 or ad_2.

Comment: Since my sdk knows only one script in which all ad's are reside, and cron is totally different from this question. As cron executes script define by your timezone, and i want to execute some string's after a specific time.